# Method .map().val(cb) does not return every object once

Tags: javascript, gun

*gun 0.8.9, Node.js*

In the [API reference](https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/API#gunmapcallback) written

> users.map().val(cb) gets each user once, including ones that are added over time.

But for me, it returns duplicates starting from the second run. The more I run the script, the more duplicates I receive.

Why? How can I list all dinosaurs from the `dinos` set without duplicates?

```
const Gun = require('gun');
const gun = new Gun({ peers: [ 'https://localhost:8888/gun' ] });

const app = gun.get('park');
const dinos = app.get('dinos');

const velociraptor = app.get('velociraptor').put({
  statistics: {
    force: 9,
    speed: 15
  }
});

const trex = app.get('trex').put({
  statistics: {
    force: 25,
    speed: 5
  }
});

dinos.set(velociraptor);
dinos.set(trex);

dinos.map().val((v, k) => {
  console.log(k);
  console.log(v);
});
```

My local data.json file content https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/8e56ca1cde4ef9875c2238a8b4c9808d